# EF code first error "The specified index already exists. [ IX_Id ]" for object tree

Tags: entity-framework

Using EF code first 4.3 I'm trying to model an object tree with a required-required relationships and a required-optional relationships.

Here is a simple representation of those classes

```
public class Top
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Middle Middle { get; set; }
}

public class Middle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the OnModelCreating code

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Top>().HasRequired(t => t.Middle).WithRequiredPrincipal().WillCascadeOnDelete();
modelBuilder.Entity<Middle>().HasRequired(t => t.Child).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

This produces the error **"The specified index already exists. [ IX_Id ]"** on SQLCE

After checking the db schema, both model binder fluent API configuration lines create an index IX_Id on the table Middles.

Does anyone know how to work around that problem?

Is there a way to set the index name?

Thank you!
Pascal

Comment: Are you trying to achieve one-to-one relationship?

Answer (score -1):

use this code ;

```
public class Top
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MiddleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MiddleId")]
    public virtual Middle Middle { get; set; }
}

public class Middle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChildId")]
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```